# My subscription is not handling errors

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components, angular2-observables

I have a subscription to a service where I request image URLs from an external API and store it in a shared service.

The Logic:
1. Empty the current images array
2. Request images from API, and push it to the (newly cleared) array   (response =>)
3. If the URL returns an error, fill up the array with default (placeholder) images (error =>)

For some reason, the error isn't being handled despite there being one.
I have posted my component and error messages for context.

Component.ts

```
  getImages(vehicleID: number, color: string): void {
    this._carConfigService.car.colors.exterior.urls = [];
    this._FAPIService.getImagesForColors(vehicleID, color)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
        response.products[0].productFormats.forEach(pF => {
        this._carConfigService.car.colors.exterior.urls.push(pF.assets[0].url);
        });
      },
        error => {
          this.errorMessage = <any>error;
          if (this._carConfigService.car.colors.exterior.urls.length === 0) {
            this._carConfigService.car.colors.exterior.urls = this._carConfigService.defaultImages;
          }
      });
  }
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 ()
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null
Uncaught Response
```

Comment: You can handle error with `onCatch` method where you wrote the service and then throw it after map then your subscribers will be able to handle it

Comment: @BabarBilal, this might be the solution I'm looking for, can you post a sample code snippet so I can mark your answer as correct? Thanks :)

Comment: Im from mobile not able to post code snippet added 2 links both have the solution to your problem good luck.

Comment: Please add your service with question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle them using a regular approach of having exception handling

```
export class TaskService {
    private _url = "api/products/datanew.json";
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }
    getTasks(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("data we got is " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Internal Server error');
    }
}
```

Also, I have a question.

1. you are getting data but you are not assigning to any object? No return type

Comment: The response I"m retrieving comes with a lot of unnecessary properties, so I traverse through the object to get only what I need and push it to an array.

I have this already integrated into my service, however I would like to update my images with default images if my subscription returned an error response.

Comment: this can be easily handled in the service itself. Why are you complicating things?

Comment: can you elaborate how the service can handle this?

Comment: what is the exact usecase you look for. May be I can help you